# How can I optimize WebPack bundle

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, svelte, snowpack

I'm working on a Svelte project, which has multiple pages (5 different html files really)
And I am using **Snowpack** for testing, **Snowpack** with **Webpack** for bundling because unbundled website have too many (over 80) requests due to separate `.js` file for each svelte component. for 4mbps net, 80 request loads within seconds, but still I think it is horrible to have 80 requests just on index page...

Problem is I'm not happy with the result from **Webpack**. I previously used **Rollup** for bundling (Svelte default) and switched to Snowpack for faster reloading.

#### Rollup result example (Very few code is duplicated due to generating separate file for each page that uses same svelte components)

**Please note that this is example, my app bundle size is around 750kb**

```
| Page       | Bundled JS                      | Size   |
|------------|---------------------------------|--------|
| index.html | index.js                        | ~40kb  |
| page1.html | page1.js                        | ~70kb  |
| page2.html | page2.js                        | ~100kb |
| page3.html | page3.js                        | ~50kb  |
| **TOTAL**  | One ideal sized JS for one page | ~260kb |
```

#### Webpack result example

**Webpack generates one big bundle and pointer-like js for each page**
**i.g. inside the index.js**

```js
(window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[]).push([[4],[],[[112,1,0]]]);
```

```
| Page       | Bundled JS                     | Size   |
|------------|--------------------------------|--------|
|            | bundle.**some_hash**.js        | ~270kb |
| index.html | index.js                       | 1kb    |
| page1.html | page1.js                       | 1kb    |
| page2.html | page2.js                       | 1kb    |
| page3.html | page3.js                       | 1kb    |
| **TOTAL**  | One big messy js for each page | ~270kb |
```

`CSS` files are one ~40kb bundle, but I used to get seperate ~7-8kb css for each page. Now so unhappy

### Bundling Details

I previously configured Rollup for multiple input/outputs, I happily ended up having ideally sized css and js for each page.

Now I use `@snowpack/plugin-webpack`, and I do not have good understanding about webpack, so I cannot modify the config for my needs..

### Desired results

I need to bundle for each page, like I got in **Rollup**, **Webpack** bundle with one big js slows down the first load dramatically. I want smaller bundle for each page, code dupe is not important because shared components are tiny.
**Please note that above is example, my app bundle size is around 750kb**

Comment: I'd go with a dual config for now -- fast Snowpack for dev and Rollup for build. Knowing Rollup build plugin for Snowpack is coming, this seems like a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split into smaller bundles by defining different entrypoints, so webpack will know where to split the code. In fact, it does not only splits, but also does a tree-shake, throwing away all the code not used.

To define the entrypoints, you'll need to (as stated in [the docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/)):

#### `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js',
   another: './src/another-module.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```